# Sonatype Nexus upload fails with Certificate for nexus.xyz.corp doesn't match common name of the certificate subject: wiki.xyz.corp

Tags: ssl, gradle, certificate, nexus

I get the following error when trying to upload files to Nexus using Gradle:

**Certificate for  doesn't match common name of the certificate subject: wiki.xyz.corp**

Details:

```
C:\data\Workspaces\httpstest>gradlew uploadArchives
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:jar SKIPPED
:uploadArchives
Could not transfer artifact com.xyz:httpstest:jar:1.0.0 from/to remo
te (https://nexus.xyz.corp/nexus/content/repositories/1st-rel/): Cer
tificate for <nexus.xyz.corp> doesn't match common name of the certi
ficate subject: wiki.xyz.corp
Could not transfer artifact com.xyz:httpstest:pom:1.0.0 from/to remo
te (https://nexus.xyz.corp/nexus/content/repositories/1st-rel/): Cer
tificate for <nexus.xyz.corp> doesn't match common name of the certi
ficate subject: wiki.xyz.corp
:uploadArchives FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':uploadArchives'.
> Could not publish configuration 'archives'
   > Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.xyz
:httpstest:jar:1.0.0 from/to remote (https://nexus.xyz.corp/nexus/co
ntent/repositories/1st-rel/): Certificate for <nexus.xyz.corp> doesn
't match common name of the certificate subject: wiki.xyz.corp
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.
BUILD FAILED
Total time: 5.511 secs
```

Downloading via HTTPS works fine, but uploading does not. 
The certificate for nexus.xyz.corp has the correct common name, and NOT wiki.xyz.corp as the error message implies.
However, wiki.xyz.corp is a different site running on the same server.

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This occurs when the different domains (wiki.xyz.corp and nexus.xyz.corp) are shared using [SNI](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication). 
It occurs at least in versions Gradle 2.5 - Gradle 2.13. The reason is that Gradle uses the Maven Wagon Library in a version that does not support SNI. In this case, the webserver returns a default certificate. It seems, that wiki.xyz.corp was defined as default certificate.

This is discussed in [Gradle Discussion](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/gradle-cant-access-maven-repos-over-tls-servers-using-sni/11986) and [Gradle Issues](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-3250).

Possible workarounds:

- Define nexus.xyz.corp as default certificate, but beware of problems on the other site
- Replace Maven Wagon with Maven Publish, but this is currently in beta. See [Maven Publish.](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/2-11-rc-1-with-https-and-wildcard-certificate-uploadarchives/14006/3)
- try to configure your system without SNI
- start Gradle in a way that host checking is disabled (this is a security leak!):

`gradlew -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true uploadArchives`